# How to fix error 'Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]' when starting tomcat

Tags: eclipse, ssl, tomcat

I'm trying to deploy my java backstage on a remote tomcat server (8.5.39). In order to use https, I changed these lines on /conf/server.xml

```
    <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="443" />
```

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" keystoreFile="xxx" keystorePass="xxx">
</Connector>
```

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="443" />
```

I can run the tomcat on remote server and I can access it by domain name(https). But when I use eclipse to run java code on remote server, it comes with error like

```
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:552)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:639)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:662)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:995)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\cert\server.jks (No such file or directory)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:100)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:72)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:244)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1105)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:224)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:581)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:993)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\cert\server.jks (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:213)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:155)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:110)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:86)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:184)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.file.ConfigFileLoader.getInputStream(ConfigFileLoader.java:89)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:190)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:272)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:239)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:98)
    ... 20 more
```

Someone told me to stop tomcat on remote server and run the code. I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: You are missing a key store file: `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\cert\server.jks (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed it. I pasted the jks file to that directory and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Your most deep exception cause is:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\cert\server.jks (No such file or directory)
```

Which is trying to find certificate to start service with SSL enabled.

In order to do that you'll have to either provide certificate file for SSL or remove https enpoint to start without any encription